# Getting arraylist from servlet to jsp as ajax response

Tags: ajax, json, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have this code in my Sevlet

```
public class ServletName extends HttpServlet{

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  ArrayList al= new ArrayList<Employee>();
  al = ApproverDao.requestGetter();  
  String json = new Gson().toJson(al);
  response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  out.write(json);
}
```

This is the JSP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#approve_btn").click(function() {
  var remarks =$('[name="result_decide"]').val();
  $.post("/ServletName/decision.do", {result_decide : remarks},
       function(responseJson) {
     var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#tabs-4')); 
      $.each(responseJson, function(index, employee) {    
       $('<tr>').appendTo($table)                
         .append($('<td>').text(employee.eName))       
         .append($('<td>').text(employee.fromDate))    
         .append($('<td>').text(employee.toDate));

});
  });
});
</script>
```

The bean:

```
class Employee{
private String eName;
private Date fromDate;
private Date toDate;
//setters and getters
}
```

How do I store this `ArrayList al` in my JSP which comes as data in the AJAX response and print it's contents in a dynamically created table?

Comment: So, have you created a service ?

Comment: This is what is in JSP @Vishal

Comment: Can you explain more ?
Do you need to send json response or plain text or html from jsp ??

Comment: I need to print the ArrayList which is in the servlet in a table that is created dynamically. The ArrayList is sent as Json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to create dynamic table using the Json ArrayList returned from your servlet.

```
$.getJSON('/ServletName/decision', function(data) {
    var table = $('<table/>').appendTo($('.adminlist'));
    $('<tr/>').appendTo(table)
              .append($('<th/>').text("Employee Name"))
              .append($('<th/>').text("To Date"))
              .append($('<th/>').text("From Date"));

    data.forEach(function(x, i) {
        var stat = data[i];
        $('<tr/>').appendTo(table)
                  .append($('<td/>').text(stat.eName))
                  .append($('<td/>').text(stat.fromDate))
                  .append($('<td/>').text(stat.toDate));
    });
});
```

It seems like the thing you missed in your code is, you are not appending the created table to any DOM element (DIV).

Comment: I have appended it to `'#tabs-4'` .

Comment: @Conquest Are you able to see dynamically created table in DOM?

Comment: No.I don't know where I'm going wrong. Plus its redirecting me to a different page. And I'm also sending data from jsp to servlet(Not shown in the code above) so I'm calling the `doPost` method of the servlet. Could that be an issue?

Comment: @Conquest 'approve_btn' is normal button or Submit button? If it is `<input type='button'>`, it should not redirect to different page. If it is redirecting to new page, it can't find '#tabs-4' in that page.. that might be the reason you are not able to see the table

Comment: So apparently it was a Submit button. But it still doesn't work. It's not redirecting me to a different page though.

Comment: Can you check your browser console to check if there are some errors.? Also print the response you are are receiving from your servlet. console.log(responseJson);

Comment: There was a missing parenthesis. Thanks a ton for your time! And for asking me to check the console!!!

Comment: If the answer satisfied your needs, you can accept the answer.