# return arraylist of objects back to an ajax call from servlet

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, arraylist

I am passing a string value to  a servlet through an ajax call in script, and retrieving corresponding data in a class object and storing it in an arraylist. Now i need this arraylist to be the 'data' that is returned to the ajax call. how to do it??

```
    `<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var selected;

            $('#txtboxvalue').change(function(){
                selected = $('#txtboxvalue').val();

                  $.ajax({
                    url: "Servlet2",
                    type: "Post",
                    data: {"txtboxvalue":selected},
                    success : function(data)
                        {
                        //here is where I want to access the returned arraylist
                        }   
});
        });
</script>
```

servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ArrayList<Cust> list2=cusName.dispCustomer2(abcd);
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(list2);
}
```

but passing like this is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting arraylist from servlet to jsp as ajax response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045163/getting-arraylist-from-servlet-to-jsp-as-ajax-response)

Comment: Check data type as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to return complex data: a list of customers.
A good format would be to send that list formatted as JSON.

On the server side get a JSON library like GSON or Jackson and serialize the list as follows:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
new Gson().toJson(list2, response.getWriter());
```

On the client side tell JQuery that you expect a JSON response.

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "Servlet2",
      type: "Post",
      data: {"txtboxvalue":selected},
      dataType: "json",
      success : function(list) {
          // list is the list as Javascript array
      }
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. That solved the problem.